# Noncompactness of $L^{p}$ space in $[-1,1]$ interval

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, lp-spaces

I want to show that for $1\leq p < \infty$, $L^{p}([-1,1])$ is not compact. I have found an example here  ( [Unit sphere in $L^p([0,1])$ is not compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1540586/unit-sphere-in-lp0-1-is-not-compact) )by constructing the following sequence

\begin{equation}
u_{j}(x) := 
\begin{cases}
2^{\frac{k}{p}}, \quad \text{if }\frac{l}{2^{k}}\leq x \leq \frac{l+1}{2^{k}}\\
0, \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Here, $j = 2^{k} + l$ and $0\leq l < 2^{k}$ with $k= 0,1,2,...$.

It is trivial to see $\forall j \in \mathbb{N}, ||u_{j}||_{L^{p}} = 1$ and thus the sequence is uniformly bounded in $L^{p}$. Now, I want to claim that $\exists \varepsilon > 0\, \forall i,j \in\mathbb{N}, i\neq j, \,||u_{i}-u_{j}||_{L^{p}}\geq \varepsilon$

Without loss of generality, I assume $i < j$ and $i = 2^{k_{i}}+l_{i}$ and $j = 2^{k_{j}}+l_{j}$. For the special case $k_{i} = k_{j}$, I can easily obtain $||u_{i}-u_{j}||_{L^{p}}= 2^{\frac{1}{p}}\geq 1$

Next, I consider the case $k_{i}<k_{j}$. if $[\frac{l_{i}}{2^{k_{i}}},\frac{l_{i}+1}{2^{k_{i}}}]\cap[\frac{l_{j}}{2^{k_{j}}},\frac{l_{j}+1}{2^{k_{j}}}]=\emptyset$, then it is also not difficult to show that $||u_{i}-u_{j}||_{L^{p}}= 2^{\frac{1}{p}}\geq 1$

My problem is that I cannot show similar bound for $[\frac{l_{i}}{2^{k_{i}}},\frac{l_{i}+1}{2^{k_{i}}}]\cap[\frac{l_{j}}{2^{k_{j}}},\frac{l_{j}+1}{2^{k_{j}}}]\neq\emptyset$

For simplicity, I start from the case $\frac{l_{j}}{2^{k_{j}}}<\frac{l_{i}}{2^{k_{i}}}<\frac{l_{j}+1}{2^{k_{j}}}<\frac{l_{i}+1}{2^{k_{i}}}$
I am stuck at this part :
$$||u_{i}-u_{j}||_{L^{p}}^{p} = 2^{k_{j}}\big(\frac{l_{i}}{2^{k_{i}}} - \frac{l_{j}}{2^{k_{j}}} \big)+ \bigg|2^{\frac{k_{j}}{p}} - 2^{\frac{k_{i}}{p}} \bigg|^{p}\big(\frac{l_{j}+1}{2^{k_{j}}} - \frac{l_{i}}{2^{k_{i}}} \big)+2^{k_{i}}\big(\frac{l_{i}+1}{2^{k_{i}}} - \frac{l_{j}+1}{2^{k_{j}}} \big)$$

I dont know how to proceed from that line above to obtain the desired lower bound. Any help will be much appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: State you question correctly. There is  a lot of difference between the statements $L^{p}$ is not compact and its unit ball is not compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote
$$
I_{k,l} = \left[\frac{l}{2^{k}},\frac{l+1}{2^k} \right],
$$
where $0\leq l<2^k$. The important observation is that if you have two of these intervals, $I_{k,l}$ and $I_{r,j}$, then either $I_{k,l}\cap I_{r,j} = \emptyset$ or $I_{k,l} \subset I_{r,j}$ if $k\geq r$. Your sequence is defined by $u_i = 2^{k/p}\chi_{I_{k,l}}$, where $i=2^{k_i}+l_i$. If $i\not= j$, assume $k_i\geq k_j$ without loss of generality. Then, we have two cases: if the intervals are disjoint, then
$$
\|u_i-u_j\|^p_p = \int_{I_{k_i,l_i}}2^{k_i}dx + \int_{I_{k_j,l_j}}2^{k_j}dx = 2.
$$
If they are not disjoint, then $I_{k_i,l_i} \subset I_{k_j,l_j}$ and we get
$$
\begin{align*}
\|u_i-u_j\|^{p}_p &= \underbrace{\int_{I_{k_i,l_i}}|2^{k_i/p}-2^{k_j/p}|^pdx}_{\geq 0} + \int_{I_{k_j,l_j}\setminus I_{k_i,l_i}}2^{k_j}dx \\
&\geq 1-\frac{1}{2^{(k_i-k_j)/p}}.
\end{align*} \\ 
$$
Note however, that $k_i>k_j$ in this case, because if $k_i=k_j$, the intervals $I_{k_i,l_i}$ and $I_{k_j,l_j}$ would not be disjoint (we are assuming $i\not=j)$. Therefore, $k_i-k_j \geq 1$, and 
$$
\|u_i-u_j\|^p_p \geq 1-\frac{1}{2^{1/p}}>0.
$$
It follows than that in any case, if $i\not= j$, $\|u_j-u_j\|_p \geq \min\{2^{1/p},(1-2^{-1/p})^{1/p}\}>0$.

Comment: Thank you, but I still do not understand for the case $I_{k_{i},l_{i}} \subset I_{k_{j},l_{j}}$, how to obtain $\int_{I_{k_{i},l_{i}}}|2^{k_{i}/p} - 2^{k_{j}/p}|^{p}dx + \int_{I_{k_{j},l_{j}}\backslash I_{k_{i},l_{i}}} 2^{k_{j}}dx = 1 - \frac{1}{2^{(k_{i}-k_{j})/p}}$

I think it is supposed to be $\geq$  not equal

Comment: You're right! I fixed it.

Comment: Are you kidding you can't delete like that a question that I spent time to answer. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3327476/representation-of-the-fourier-laplace-transform-of-the-sphere-surface-measure/3327484#3327484